# greater than / less than not avialable in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm using the SharePoint Designer to build a SP2013 Workflow.
I have to compare two values with greater than / less than, but i can't seem to find it.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion?
[image: SharePoint if operator selection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These operators appear for strings, while you are trying to compare numbers. You must cast the values as number by creating number variables and giving them the values of the strings you are trying to compare.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried changing the variable types to number, aswell as integer for both variables. I still get the same dropdown selection

Comment: Would you mind precising the action you are trying to make. I have tried the solution I gave you, and it works.

Comment: You started off blank with the variable after the change ?

Comment: @AbnerPeter First im getting the number of items in a list via an HTTP REST call, this number I save into a variable of type number. Next I set another number variable to 9000. After that all i want to do is compare the two values.
In my first attempt I typed 9000 into the if-statement, since that didn't work I've also put it into a number variable as mentioned above.

Comment: When I type a value, it is indeed detected as a string which gives the operators you gave as a screenshot, however, when i put the first value as a workflow variable, which i created through the ribbon "Local Variables" as a number type, i do have the correct operators for numbers. try to reproduce that simple case and go through each difference in your example.

Comment: @AbnerPeter I've found the problem: I was typing the variables into the if statement manually, instead of selecting them via the popup. Thank's for your help though :)